# I cannot deploy node application and mongodb container into aws using ecs. For deploying, I used aws ECS and used one task for holding two containers

Tags: node.js, mongodb, devops, amazon-ecs

I can run these two containers in my local machine but failed in the aws ecs cluster.

[The task error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uP36X.jpg)[The task log page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3eoE.jpg)[node js application container configuration page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuiyY.jpg)[mongodb container configuration page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IkL5.jpg)

The code for connecting mongodb in nodejs is below.

```
mongoose.connect(
  `mongodb://${process.env.MONGODB_USERNAME}:${process.env.MONGODB_PASSWORD}@${process.env.MONGODB_URL}:27017/course-goals?authSource=admin`,
  {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  },
  (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('FAILED TO CONNECT TO MONGODB');
      console.error(`mongodb://${process.env.MONGODB_USERNAME}:${process.env.MONGODB_PASSWORD}@${process.env.MONGODB_URL}:27017/course-goals?authSource=admin`)
      console.error(err);
    } else {
      console.log('CONNECTED TO MONGODB!!');
      app.listen(80);
    }
  }
);
```

I tried to deploy only mongodb container and connect it from my local machine with the admin account and password, it worked.